# Best Approach To Retrieve Search Result

Tags: asp.net, post, curl, get, search-engine

I am trying to write a program that extracts shipping container information from a specific site. I've had success with several shipping companies wbsites that use POST methods to submit searches. For these sites I have been using cURL, a PHP libary. However, this one site http://www.cma-cgm.com/eBusiness/Tracking/ has been very difficult to interact with. I have tried using cURL but all I retrieve is the surrounding html without the actual search results.

A sample container I am trying to track is CMAU1173561.

The actual tracking URL seems to be http://www.cma-cgm.com/eBusiness/Tracking/Default.aspx?ContNum=CMAU1173561&T=292012319448 where ContNum is the shipping container and T is a value constructed from current time.

I also noted the .aspx. What is the best approach for retrieving these search results programatically?